# How to take NSString after specific character which occurs multiple time in NSString?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have a complete URL, say

```
http://www.mywebsite.com//Folder /Detals /Final Image /La Image Logo.jpg
```

Here in this NSString, I only want to fetch

```
La Image Logo.jpg
```

How can I do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[string lastPathComponent]` should do the trick

Comment: Consider the URL `@"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/75a56ad14871ad02306a067380d8e1fa.jpg?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"` to see the disadvantage of this approach.

Comment: Good point indeed. Thanks for the comment. Depending on the case, converting to NSURL could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

If it's about the filename in a URL you should definitely create an `NSURL` object and query that object for the desired information:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com//Folder /Detals /Final Image /La Image Logo.jpg"];
NSString *filename = [url lastPathComponent];
```

`NSURL` is good at parsing URL strings. This way you're sure that you don't get any fragment part ("#anchor") or parameters ("?q=foo&p=bar") in your filename.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSString *string=[[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject]`